# Django 1.7.1: Child model, remove all references to parent model and make child model inherit from grandpa instead

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have three models like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass
    # more fields here

class B(A):
    pass
    # more fields here

class C(B):
    pass
    # more fields here
```

New requirements require me to instead have:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass
    # more fields here

class B(A):
    pass
    # more fields here

class C(A):
    pass
    # more fields here
```

The code is already running in production, so I need to do some data migration. Thinking that it would work smoothly, here's what I planned to do:

1. Save each `C`'s `b_ptr_id` to a temporary field.
2. Remove `C`'s inheritance from `B` (deleting `b_ptr_id` in the process).
3. Make `C` inherit from `A` (adding an `a_ptr_id` in the process).
4. For each `C`, copy the value stored in the temporary field to `a_ptr_id`.
5. Delete the temporary field.

My problem is with step 3. When I try to make inherit `C` from `A`, I'm getting the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'a_ptr' in class 'C' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'B'`. So it seems like Django still "remembers" that `C` used to inherit from `B`, **even if `b_ptr_id` is no longer a column of `C` in the database**. How do I make it forget so that I can move on? Or is there a better way to make child models inherit from its grandparent model instead of its parent model?

Comment: It wont refer to B as base class unless you have inherited B in C

Comment: @AswinMurugesh `C` used to inherit `B`, but even after removing the inheritance, it's still referring to `B` as base class. The `b_ptr_id` is not even a column in `C`'s table anymore. I don't know where else Django stores the information about the model hierarchies.

Comment: After changing the schema, did you do a migrate?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Yes, I did. I immediately apply the migration after each step I described above.

Comment: There might be possibilities of pseudo/phantom migrations. Try logging in to your db and seeing if the migration has actually happened

Comment: @AswinMurugesh I've checked the db and the migration has actually happened, I can clearly see that the column referring to `B` doesn't exist in the table of `C` anymore. By the way, thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's an easier way to do this but....

Try creating a C' that inherits A. 
Then create a program that creates a C' instance of each C instance. 
(Delete all instance of C afterwards)

If you want to keep the name C, update schema for C and then repopulate C from the C' instances.

Hope it helps. :)