# Django migrations refuse to acknowledge a model no longer inherits from old parent

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm trying to remove a concrete parent model and copy some of its fields directly onto the child. I have performed a similar process several times before using South (the same parent model on other children), but since upgrading to Django 1.7, it's just not playing the game. Django gives the following error during the `migrate` process:

```
FieldError: Local field <field_name> in class <child_model> clashes with field of similar name from base class <parent_model>
```

At the point that both `makemigrations` and `migrate` are run and this error occurs, the parent model no longer appears in the code as the parent of the class, yet the migration still complains.

A similar question [has been asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947888/) and the accepted solution involves creating a new model, copying data to it, replacing the existing model, and copying the data back. Unfortunately, this approach will not work in my case. It is an established model with numerous foreign keys pointing back to it, which would be lost if the original records were removed.

The (simplified) approach I used under South was:

1. Remove the model as the parent and add the new fields to the child
2. Add an explicit primary key field with the same name as the old auto `*_ptr_id` field
3. Run `schemamigration` and edit the file to:

   - Remove South's attempt to remove and recreate the `*_ptr` field
   - Add some custom logic to remove the ForeignKey-ness of the `*_ptr_id` field and add PrimaryKey-ness
4. Use a `datamigration` to grab the values off the old parent and add them to the new fields on the child

This is the approach I was hoping would be reasonably easily adapted to native Django migrations, and I got (with some tweaking) the `*_ptr_id` field replacement logic going. But Django won't let me add the new fields. I have tried the following:

- Removing the parent model and performing the custom `*_ptr_id` replacement, migrating, and adding the fields as a second migration.
- Removing the parent model and *not* editing the file to manually mess with `*_ptr_id`, but leaving Django's remove/add operations and migrating with `--fake`.

In both scenarios, a later migration that adds new fields with the same name as those on the old parent causes the above error. Django refuses to acknowledge that the old parent model is no longer a parent of the class.

Has anyone else had this problem and been able to work around it?

**Edit:**

This appears to be caused by the `bases` argument of the `CreateModel` schema operation class listing the parent model, and the lack of a matching operation to update the list. The [documentation for `CreateModel`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#createmodel) lists this argument as optional, but are there any side-effects to manually changing this value in a previously applied migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hitting this same problem in Django 1.11, I followed the edited advice and found the initial 'CreateModel' call in my migrations files. Commenting out the `bases=('{appname}.{modelname}',),` line and explicitly setting my model's primary key to be 'id' then re-running `makemigrations` and `migrate` fixed the issue for me.

I'm not sure if the primary key change is relevant to the solution, I'm just laying out variables.

Another option for people less invested in their model name (and data): rename it when you remove the parent. Note that while this worked for me, switching back to the original model name in another migration hit this same "once a child, always a child" error, so you'll still need to edit the 'bases=' line in your migrations.

Thanks oogles and Community!

Comment: Yep, after finding no other alternative and getting no response here, I also ended up editing that ``bases`` line. I haven't noticed any ill effects since. And since I neglected to come back and answer this as such, you, sir, just earned yourself an accepted answer ;).